# Check if a DLL is changed after memory load

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, process, hook

I'm try to find a fast and effective way to allow a dll to check if code it's changed on memory.

I'd like to inserted into THISLIB.DLL class a function tht use something like:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Module[] thisModule = assembly.GetLoadedModules();
foreach (Module i in thisModule)
{
    if (i.Name == "THISLIB.dll")
    {
        ModuleHandle m= i.ModuleHandle;
        byte[] dllMemory = new byte[??? HOW GET THISLIB.DLL MEMORY SIZE ???];
        dllMemory = ??? HOW GET THISLIB.DLL MEMORY DATA ???
    }
}
```

I need to check if HASH(MEMORY THISLIB.DLL) is equal to HASH(FILESYSTEM THISLIB.DLL)!

Comment: Use a filesystemwatcher to check for dll file updates. Read the file in as a bytestream to access the bytes.

Comment: can't you just check the file access/creation time? or use some FileSystemWatcher?

Comment: This is already built into the CLR, it can verify the strong name of an assembly.  Just use Project + Properties, Signing.  If you run in full trust and still want to verify the strong name then google StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx.

Comment: I need a solution that give me the byte array of DLL loaded into memory...